# python, matplotlib: Instead of a plot, i'm getting values of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I have an array, including 9600 int elements from csv file and I want to plot it, using matplotlib library. Unfortunately, what I'm getting is a blank plot and my data is printed like an array. Below, I'd like to show You how it looks: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzgRy.png)

Also, I would like to show You some part of my code:

```
def data_loader(filename):
    emgfile = open(f"measurements/{filename}", "r")
    emgdata = emgfile.read()
    data_plotter(emgdata)

def data_plotter(received_data):
    plt.plot(received_data)
    plt.show()
```

What I want to achieve, is plot with my data from csv file on y axis. I'm using PyCharm EDU and Windows 10.

Comment: what do the first few lines of your data file look like?

Comment: It looks like this: 133
131
130
128
127
125
128
130
133

Comment: OK so that is a list of **single** numbers. To plot on a graph you need a list of **pairs** of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you called plt.plot(), you plotted a string. To avoid this, you will have to plot a list. You will have to change your functions to this:

```
def data_plotter(received_data):
    plt.plot(received_data)
    plt.show()

def data_loader(filename):
    emgfile = open(filename, 'r')
    emgdata = emgfile.read()
    data_plotter(emgdata.split(', ')) # use whatever separator you need to split it into a list
```

Comment: fair enough so how to do it ? I need some extra arguments in plt.plot() or what ?

Comment: You can use the .split() method to split it into a list, then plot it

Comment: ok, now it's working much better but I'm getting messy plot, nevertheless thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you have called for the matplotlib library at the beginning of youe code.

Comment: I did this, by doing: 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' at the beginning of code

Comment: the code wouldnt even run if he didn't, plt would be empty and code would crash